# Div type="hidden" + Not hided

Tags: javascript, html, visibility

In my code, I have a `div` tag with `type="hidden"`. I just don't want to show the `div`. If needed, I will show it using JQuery `Show()`.

But, using this, my `div` is not hidden from view.

Edit:
    Now I hide the `div` by using

```html
<div style="visibility:hidden">XYZ</div>
```

If I need to show it again, how can I?

Comment: Visibilty is a style: <div style="display: none">

Answer (score 34, accepted):

try using style instead of type

```
<div style="display: none;">content</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
type="hidden"
```

is used only for hidden input textbox.

If you want to hide you div use :

```
style="display:none"
```

Or with JQuery hide your div with [hide()](http://docs.jquery.com/API/1.1/Effects/Animations#hide.28.29).

Answer (score 4):

Use `display: none` to prevent the div from being displayed and layout space won't be reserved.
Use `visibility: hidden` to simply hide it (like 0% opacity), but the necessary space will be reserved.

Comment: this is the best answer

Answer (score 2):

If the DIV isn't *absolutely* positioned, "*display:none*" can crash the overall structure of the document.
You may use:

```
<div style="visibility:hidden"></div>
```

This will make the DIV invisible.

Comment: Just for clarification: While display:none "collapses" the particular element, visibility:hidden hides it while reserving the space for it in the layout.

Comment: After i make it hidden , if i need to show the Div on click of a some Text .Jow can i do
..

Answer (score 0):

By using style="display:none" , can hide the div

Answer (score 0):

Define a id for that element

To hide element in javascript

```
document.getElementById('elementId').style.display= 'none' ;
```

To hide element in javascript

```
document.getElementById('elementId').style.display= 'block' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way. Let's say you have:

```
<div hidden>content</div>
```

In the css:

```
div[hidden] {
  display: none;
}
```